# Doing Map<Key, Map<Key, Set< Class>>> is painful in C++. Is there a better way?

Tags: c++, dictionary, set, code-organization

I'm used to Python's development mindset when it comes to organizing data in a hierarchical fashion using maps. It's easy and syntactically cheap. While not extremely difficult in C++, nested maps/sets make organization difficult. I don't think I'm thinking about the problem right.

As an example, I'm using the following organization:

```
typedef set<Motif> Motifs;

typedef map<Motif, Motifs> LinkedMotifs;

struct Candidates {
    Motifs deadend;
    Motifs intralinked;
    LinkedMotifs interlinked;
};

typedef map<Linker::shp, Candidates> LinkedCandidates;
```

For performance reasons, I'm using boost's flat_map/set implementations. Motif is a std::pair of structs. Linker::shp is a SharedPtr.

This map is the result of a search function. After the search is completed, I score the results and in a separate function I write the results out to a file. I designed the project with functional programming in mind and m original attempt was to keep the candidate structure and the score structure separated. This, however, created problems as I basically end up recreating all of the map structure in memory. The structure is important when everything is written out to disk.

I could link scores to the iterators in the maps and sets, but it honestly seems like I'm making things too difficult.

Thanks!

*Edited to make more sense to my end goals.

Comment: IMO it looks quite fine as is, provided the choice for collections makes sense.

Comment: What is the question/problem here? I don't see a question anywhere in the text...

Answer (score 3):

Note that majority of the verbosity of your code comes from repetitive usage of that "sequence and config pair" in all names. That indicates that you need a term to address that. Best is to use same term that is used in problem domain slang to name it. Humans are lazy. Lets say they call it as `motif` and everything becomes lot simpler:

```
typedef set<Motif> Motifs;

typedef map<Motif, Motifs> LinkedMotifs;

struct Candidates {
    Motifs deadend;
    Motifs intralinked;
    LinkedMotifs interlinked;
};

typedef map<Linker::shp, Candidates> LinkersCandidates;
```

IOW ... use short names. Always put every name into namespace in C++. C++ is usually used to
write rather large products (million of lines is sort of average) and that helps to
avoid name collisions.

If you need to reuse that organization then you can use template:

```
template<typename T>
struct Handler {
    typedef set<T> Ts;

    typedef map<T, Ts> LinkedTs;

    struct Candidates {
        Ts deadend;
        Ts intralinked;
        LinkedTs interlinked;
    };

    typedef map<Linker::shp, Candidates> LinkersCandidates;
};

typedef Handler<Motif>::LinkersCandidates LinkersMotifCandidates;
typedef Handler<Other>::LinkersCandidates LinkersOtherCandidates;
```

The performance issues may arise if you use copies where you should use references or pointers or that you did not choose correct containers. For example when `set`s and `map`s are not sophisticated enough then [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) or [Boost.Graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/graph/doc/table_of_contents.html) offer more complex containers. On the other hand when `map` or `set` stays immutable most of the time then sorted `vector` of pairs (instead of `map`) or sorted `vector` (instead of `set`) and `std::lower_bound` may offer better performance. Copying `set`s and `map`s is far more expensive than copying `vector`s.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using namespaces. My concern is less the verbosity and more organization related.

For example, I have another structure after this. I'm having to recreate this entire structure over again for a different datatype because I need to point to the exact same information.

Comment: Sorry, I need to be clear. I have additional information that needs to link to a particular entry in the map, but all of the keys leading up to it are important to functionality later on.

Comment: Yes, seems that you need to edit the question. Code that you posted is simple. It feels that it does not attempt to solve the issue that you actually have.

Comment: Edited. Hope that makes more sense.